# Is there an event that fires when a browser scrolls to a named anchor?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When linking to a page using a named anchor e.g. `page.html#heading` the browser will load the page, then jump down to the anchor. Is there a browser event that fires when this has completed?

To explain my reasons behind it: I want to use the event to trigger an animation in the browser.

Comment: Any luck with this? I find myself needing such an event.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the hash triggers the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange).

However, I don't think it fires when loading a url where the link already has the hash set. *But* you can check the hash (`location.hash`) on page load if you want a certain script to run depending on the hash.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the hashchange event but that fires, as you'd expect, when the window detects the hashed value in the URL. I am after the more specific event of the window finishing scrolling to the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

In Safari 7.0.3 on the Mac this works...

HTML has:

```
<a id="jumper" href="#aa">Jump</a>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var j = document.getElementById("jumper");

j.addEventListener("click", registerAnchorJump);

function registerAnchorJump(e) {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", unregisterAnchorJump);
}

function unregisterAnchorJump(e) {
    // trigger your animation...
    console.log(window.scrollY);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll",unregisterAnchorJump);
}
</script>
```

Fancy footwork to prevent constant firing of scroll event as user scrolls window normally.