# Alternative to jquery scroll() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for a small project I am working on, I've implemented a function that fires anytime the user scrolls on the website. for example, when scrolling past a certain point, a navigation bar sticks to the top. 
Now my problem is, I am binding the 'scroll' method

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){})
```

to handle these events.
But now I would like to use anchors, which means when clicking on an anchor, the site **jumps** to a certain point. As it doesn't scroll, the function listening for scrolls won't be fired, even though the page content jumped to another point.

Now my question is, is there a similar event to 'scroll' that won't just listen on scrolls, but on every page event that moves the current coordinates of the page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question: [Is there an event that fires when a browser scrolls to a named anchor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299220/is-there-an-event-that-fires-when-a-browser-scrolls-to-a-named-anchor)

Comment: Can you post a snippet or fiddle to show it to us, because  'scroll' event also works on anchor navigation. Because it is still scrolling, you just can't see it because it is instant.