# Detecting a scroll to an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor

Consider the following scenario:

- There's an anchor on the page, e.g. `<a id='apples'...`
- The user visits `https://example.com/thing.html#apples`. The browser loads the page, and scrolls to the anchor.
- The user scrolls away, then decides that they want to see apples again, so they click inside the address bar, hit enter, and the browser scrolls to the apples anchor again.

Question is: how do I detect that?

- The `scroll` event could work, but then I'd have to differentiate it from other types of user-initiated scrolling, like mouse wheel, keyboard, or even the scroll bar
- `hashchange` doesn't fire, because well, the hash didn't change indeed
- No `load` event either, as the page didn't need reloading

Is there an event I didn't think of?

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299220/is-there-an-event-that-fires-when-a-browser-scrolls-to-a-named-anchor (and perhaps slightly disapointing)

Comment: Thanks... that's the harsh reality I was afraid of :)