# Fire event when arriving in page with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, anchor

My question is a little bit like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299220/is-there-an-event-that-fires-when-a-browser-scrolls-to-a-named-anchor) but not exactly the same.

I have a page with an anchor, eg. `page.html#video1`. In this page, I have multiple sections with ids, e. `#video1`, `#video2`. Each section contains an article and a button that shows a video.

I want the video in section `#video1` to be displayed automatically when arriving to `page.html#video1`. Is that possible with Javascript or jQuery?

```html
<div id="video_container"></div>
<div id="video"></div>

<section id="video1">
  <p>
    article 1
  </p>
  <button class="video1">
   the button that plays the video1
  </button>
</section>

<section id="video2">
  <p>
    article 2
  </p>
  <button class="video2">
   the button that plays the video2
  </button>
</section>
```

```js
$('.video1').click(function() {
  $("#video_container").html('<div id="video"><iframe id="portrait_video" class="video_fonc" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0itBZI6PiDc?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe></div>').fadeIn(400);
  $("#video").fitVids();
});

$('.video2').click(function() {
  $("#video_container").html('<div id="video"><iframe id="portrait_video" class="video_fonc" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0itBZI6PiDc?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe></div>').fadeIn(400);
  $("#video").fitVids();
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aczekqgv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the fragment from the URL using `window.location.hash`. In your case this value will match with the `id` of the `section` containing the button, so you can simply find the related `button` and `trigger()` a click on it:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash) {
  $('section#' + hash).find('button').trigger('click');
}
```